# How to monitor multiple devices with fw1-loggrabber

Tags: linux, security, logging, firewall, checkpoint

I am currently working on a logging system where i need to pull logs out of Checkpoint devices.
I use fw1-loggrabber with OPSEC LEA, and I successfully pulled logs from a Checkpoint firewall.

Now let's say i have 100 devices. 
do I need to configure and run fw1-loggrabber 100 times or can I use one lea.conf and fw1-loggrabber.conf to configure all the devices I want to monitor and run it?

My currently configured files:

lea.conf:

```
lea_server auth_type sslca
lea_server ip 255.255.255.255
lea_server auth_port 18184
lea_server port 18184
opsec_sic_name "CN=Test,O=test..hi7arv"
lea_server opsec_entity_sic_name "cn=tt_mgmt,o=test..hi7arv"
opsec_sslca_file /opt/pkg_rel/p12_cert_file
```

fw1-loggrabber.conf

```
DEBUG_LEVEL="0"
FW1_LOGFILE="fw.log"
FW1_OUTPUT="logs"
FW1_TYPE="ng"
FW1_MODE="normal"
ONLINE_MODE="yes"
SHOW_FIELDNAMES="yes"
DATEFORMAT="std"
SYSLOG_FACILITY="LOCAL1"
RESOLVE_MODE="no"
RECORD_SEPARATOR="|"
LOGGING_CONFIGURATION=file
OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX="/var/log/testFolder/Checkpoint/fw1"
OUTPUT_FILE_ROTATESIZE=1048576
```

If not possible to configure and run all from one configuration file (or two), any alternatives for pulling logs using Checkpoint OPSEC LEA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the fw1-loggrabber simply run it with as many lea.conf configs as you like - it will run on as many devices as you want.

Example:

```
/usr/local/fw1-loggrabber/bin/fw1-loggrabber
-c /usr/local/fw1-loggrabber/fw1-loggrabber.conf
-l /usr/local/fw1-loggrabber/lea1.conf
-l /usr/local/fw1-loggrabber/lea2.conf
```

Comment: I was not able to get logs from multiple devices using this approach. It only fetches log from the last config that we provide. Is this possible with only the latest version of fw1-loggrabber?

Comment: Hmm. Checking the source code of fw1-loggrabber, it seems that you are correct and it's weird it worked at all in my use-case a year and a half ago... Unfortunately, our project is long abandoned, but I will try looking into it.